# vue can not get component ref when using dynamic components and dynamic import

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue page with some components.
I want load components by dynamic configuration, but I always get component ref as `undefined`:

```html
<template>
  ...
  <template v-for="com in components">
    <component :is="com.name" :ref="el => setComponents(com.key,el)"/>
  </template>
</template>
<script>
  ...
  components: {
    Com1: () => import('/@/views/common/com1.vue'),
    Com2: () => import('/@/views/common/com2.vue'),
  },
  setup() {
    const components = [
      {name: 'Com1', key: "Com1"},
      {name: 'Com2', key: "Com2"},
    ];
    const comRefs = {};
    const setComponents = (key, el) => {
      // el always get undefined
      console.log('setComponents', key, el);
      comRefs[key] = el;
    }
    return {
      components,
      setComponents
    }
  }
</script>
```

If I import components without dynamic, it works fine:

```html
<script>
  import Com1 from '/@/views/common/com1.vue';
  import Com2 from '/@/views/common/com2.vue';
  ... 
  components: {
    Com1,
    Com2,
  },
  setup() {
    const components = [
      {name: 'Com1', key: "Com1"},
      {name: 'Com2', key: "Com2"},
    ];
    const comRefs = {};
    const setComponents = (key, el) => {
      // right now I can get the components refs
      console.log('setComponents', key, el);
      comRefs[key] = el;
    }
    return {
      components,
      setComponents
    }
  }
</script>
```

Is it possible to get dom refs with dynamic component and dynamic import ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ref` is always `undefined` because the specified component is unknown (because of invalid declarations in the `components` option).

In Vue 3, [async components must be declared with `defineAsyncComponent()`](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#_3-x-syntax):

```js
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Com1: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('/@/views/common/com1.vue')),
    Com2: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('/@/views/common/com2.vue')),
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ref-to-dynamic-component?file=src/components/MyComponent.vue)